# Is this capacitor arrangement parallel or in series?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, capacitance

I came across this situation :

A 2 μF capacitor is charged by a battery and after that battery is removed and an 8 μF capacitor is connected to the charged 2 μF capacitor.

Now charge would flow from 2 μF capacitor until voltage across both the capacitors is same.

We have to find how much energy got dissipated while doing so.

I searched internet and I found that we can find energy dissipated if we consider our combination of both the capacitors as parallel.

We can get resultant capacitance after adding their individual capacitance like we do in parallel combination; our charge would remain same and we could simply find final energy stored in combination and subtract initial energy stored in 2 μF and we get our energy dissipated.

[image: Circuit diagram of capacitors]

But I am very confused because the configuration of both the capacitors don't look parallel to me. They look like they are in series. Current can flow from one capacitor to other like in series combination.

So can anyone explain why they are considered in parallel

Comment: Note that both ends of capacitors are connected to each other. This is parallel combination

Comment: @Tojra but current can flow from one capacitor to other like in series combination

Comment: Connect end-to-end two resistors, does it matter how you call that connection? If you want to know how two capacitors together behave assign labels at their ends, connect the pair to some source and look at voltages and the currents between them; it does not matter what you call that connection.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are the capacitors in this circuit in parallel but not in series?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/579916/)

Comment: they are really parallel. current can flow on both sides .